# Calculation of average required series of integers, equal to a defined double

Tags: java, arrays, logic, average

**Hello!**
I am trying to make a **Java** program to generate a **series of Integers** from a given array, such that the **average** of the **selected integers** is equal to a user-defined double.

Now, let's say the **User** defines the target as **46.00**.

```
ArrayList<Integer> usableItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, the user specifies the size and each integer into the array. Like this.

```
System.out.println("Enter number of elements of usable integers: ");
int siz=0;
siz = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
ArrayList<Integer> usableItems = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0 ; i<siz ; i++)
{
     try {
          int j = i+1;
          System.out.println("Enter element "+j+": ");
          usableItems.add(Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()));
     } catch (Exception e)
     {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          break;
     }
}
```

Let's say, this is the specified array:

```
[20,25,30,35,50]
```

So, it should process now, so that I get this output:

```
Specified target = 46.00
Series = 50,50,50,50,30
```

As the average of the above outputted series is equal to **46**.
The number of integers in the **Series** (which is 5), need not be equal to the size of the **usableItems**.

I tried to find an accurate **algorithm**, but I don't get it how to.

Any **helps**/**suggestions** are surely appreciated!

Comment: using all combinations of 1 in 5, 2 in 5, 3 in 5, 4 in 5, 5 in 5, an compute the average for each ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute-force recursive implementation returning the shortest possible series:

```
public List<Integer> matchAverage(double target, List<Integer> items) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { // arbitrary limit of 50
        List<Integer> match = matchAverage(target, items, new ArrayList<>(), 0, i);
        if (match != null) return match;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Average not found.");
}

private List<Integer> matchAverage(double target, List<Integer> items, List<Integer> selected, int sum, int left) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Integer item = items.get(i);
        selected.add(item);
        sum += item;
        if (left == 1) {
            if (sum / (double) selected.size() == target) {
                return selected;
            }
        } else {
            List<Integer> match = matchAverage(target, items.subList(i, items.size()), selected, sum, left - 1);
            if (match != null) return match;
        }
        sum -= item;
        selected.remove(selected.size() - 1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can probably do this a lot faster by only checking items that get you closer to the target.